# Have multiple objects in a With statement in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I have a lot of labels in VB that I use in `With` statement to set their properties.

**Problem**
Is there any way I can do something like the following:

```
With lblA, lblB, lblC
    .fontColor = color.Red
End With
```

Is this possible, or do I have to manually do a `With` statement for each of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would keep those types of items in a list and then apply a for each loop on them, assuming they are all of the same type (or at least base type). Assuming you are using controls of type `label` this would be a solution. Note that I've modified `.fontColor` to `.ForeColor` so that this example works with the Label class:

```
Dim lblList as new List(of Label) ({lblA, lblB, lblC})
lblList.ForEach(sub(x) x.Fore Color = color.red)
```

Since you've posted your solution, you could still do the following to avoid the iteration loop over the array you made (which is why I do this as a list) not having to take into account the array size or anything:

```
 lblList.ForEach(Sub(x)
                    With x
                       .BackColor = Color.Black
                       .Dock = DockStyle.Top
                       .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                    End With
                 End Sub)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a shorter and more readable version of your solution:

```
For Each lbl As Label In {lblA, lblB, lblC}
  With lbl
    '...
  End With
Next
```

Comment: @Freelensia You must be using C#. This code is for VB.NET.

Comment: VBA for Excel @Neolisk?

Comment: @Freelensia There are might be some similarities in syntax between VB.NET and VBA. But in general, .NET code will not work on VBA. If you have a VBA question, please look for existing answers on Stack Overflow, and if not already answered, feel free to ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I ended up doing it:

```
Dim arrayMe As Label() = {lblA, lblB, lblC}
For count = 0 To arrayMe.Length - 1 Step 1
    With arrayMe(count)
        .BackColor = Color.Black
        .Dock = DockStyle.Top
        .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    End With
Next
```

There are other ways to do it, but I found this to be useful.

Comment: Compare readability of this vs For Each. As a general rule of thumb, it only makes sense to have a regular/indexed loop if you cannot write a For Each (for example, non-linear traverse). When using Resharper, it can instantly convert between the two.