# Can "with" keyword in VB.Net be used with multiple class objects

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to use **With** keyword with multiple class objects/controls in vb.net?

I can use it like:

```
With something
    .property = value
End With
```

But, is it possible to use it with multiple class objects?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446068/have-multiple-objects-in-a-with-statement-in-vb

Comment: So, it says I need to create a list of identical class. But what if the objects are not the instance of same class?

Comment: This was my next question, I posted and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible, you can nest them, but that's about it:

```
With something1
    .property1 = value

     With something2
        .property2 = .property1 'something2.property2 = something1.property1
     End Width
End With
```

And it is really easy to get lost using this approach, especially if there're common properties between objects, so it is not recommended.

Comment: I wrote separate "With"s -- that is neat and clean without conflicts. I was just wondering if it was allowed. @Yuriy: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I tought the code in the second with would ignore the first with.

Comment: @the_lotus no, within the second `with` you can access properties of the first, but it is easy to forget which object you're looking at

Comment: @YuriyGalanter "However, because members of outer statements are masked inside the inner statements, you must provide a fully qualified object reference in an inner With block to any member of an object in an outer With block." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @the_lotus that's a given. This is why I made a note about common properties in my answer.